# Confusion about blow up of affine variety and exceptional set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider for example the affine cone $X = V(X^2+Y^2-Z^2)$. It has a singularity at $0$, where we will blow it up.

As far as I know, the blow up is given by the variety
$$\hat X = \{( (X,Y,Z),[u:v:w])\in \mathbb A^3 \times \mathbb P^2|~ Xv= Yu, ~Xw = Zu,~ Yw= Zv, X^2 + Y^2=Z^2\}  $$

To me it seems like that $(0,0,0)\times \mathbb P^2\subset \hat X $
(if I set $X=Y=Z=0$, then i can freely chose $[u:v:w]$).

But this does not seem right to me. For example because of dimension reasons.

Comment: Your $\hat{X}$ is actually blowing up 3-space at the origin and then taking the total transform of your conic, not blowing up the conic at the origin. To get this, you must take the proper transform, which means you must remove the exceptional divisor $(0,0,0)\times\mathbb{P}^2$ from $\hat{X}$ and then take its closure.

Comment: @Mohan: How do I do this? I thought I can work with these equations?

Comment: No, you can not work with just these equations.

Comment: So, what do i need to do? please help me. @Mohan

Comment: Is it, that the equations hold everywhere on the blow up, but the blow up may not consist of all points where the equations hold?

Comment: To get the blow up, you need one more equation, $u^2+v^2-w^2=0$. This can be seen, by multiplying this by say $X^2$ and use your other equations to get zero. Similarly with $Y^2, Z^2$. So, the closure outside the origin gives you this extra equation and then you can check that this is in fact the blow up.

Comment: I don't really se the logic. The equation $u^2 + v^2 -w^2 = 0$ is clearly true, because it is a sonsequence of the other equations. So what do I gain from it?

Comment: It is not a consequence of the other equations.

Comment: @Mohan: Ok, the equation $X^2(u^2+v^2-w^2)=0$ is a consequence of the other equations. But how do I proceed then? Away from the exceptional divisor, $X\neq0$, so there the equation $(u^2+v^2-w^2)$ holds indeed. But why does demanding the equation to hold everywhere define the closure?

Comment: As I said, similarly, $Y^2(u^2+v^2-w^2)=Z^2(u^2+v^2-w^2)=0$, so outside the origin you get what you want and thus the closure is contained in this.

Comment: @Mohan: So, the set given by my equations above + $u^2+v^2-w^2=0$ is closed and contains $\hat X\setminus (0,0,0)\times \mathbb P^2$. But why is it its closure, i.e. why is it the smallest such set?  

Also, does this approach always work? If I low up the variety given by $f(X,Y,Z)$, then the blow up is given by the usual equations + $f(u,v,w)$, resp does it work if $f$ is homogeneous?